# How to stop infinite loop of componentDidUpdate?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a click event on button. I am using that event to generate a number. then i am using template strings for fetching data from API.
I am placing my code in componentDidUpdate, which i is going into infinite loop but when i am using conditions like below code it is not running even the first time. I guess it is because of initial state.info is already equal to prevState.info that is why it is not able to pass through if condition. Any idea how to go around this code...

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState){
  if (prevState.info !== this.state.info){
  const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${this.state.randNumber}`
  fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data=>{
       const info =[];
       info.push(data);
       this.setState({info:info})

  })
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```js
if (prevState.info !== this.state.info) {
```

use this:

```js
if (prevState.randNumber !== this.state.randNumber) {
```

The request you're making is dependent on `randNumber`. That's why you need to check for changes to it, which will make the request fire when you want. You don't need to check for changes to `info`, because it's never read inside the `if` statement. It's only written to (with the response data). This will also avoid the infinite loop.

Another option you should consider is moving the body of the `if` statement into the button click event handler.

If you need that request to always run in response to any change to `randNumber`, and multiple sources can change it, then your approach of using `componentDidUpdate` is ideal. If you only need to make the request in response to the button click, writing your code directly in the click handler for that button is simpler.

Answer (score -1):

One way to handle such situations is to export the functionality to a method (eg. `fetchData` method bellow). Then you can have the desired behavior with what is built for it. `componentDidUpdate` is built to run functions on mount. Then use `componentDidUpdate` for the next updates.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.fetchData()
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevState.info !== this.state.info) {
    this.fetchData()
  }
}

fetchData() {
  const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${this.state.randNumber}`
  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      const info = []
      info.push(data)
      this.setState({ info })
    })
}
```

Comment: This will still trigger the infinite loop, it just happens on mount now :) Extracting a function doesn't get to the root of the problem. I tried to explain the problem in my answer.